# context.getUrl() does not return an XSPUrl?

Tags: xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

xpage with extlib application layout (bootstrap). I want to change the user language by buttons/links in the utility links section of the application layout:

I tried it quite straight like:

```
<xe:basicLeafNode label="DE">
    <xe:this.href>
    <![CDATA[${javascript:return context.getUrl().setParameter("mylang","de");}]]>
    </xe:this.href>
</xe:basicLeafNode>
```

But this returns an empty string. I had to do it much more complicated:

```
<xe:basicLeafNode label="DE">
    <xe:this.href>
    <![CDATA[${javascript:var langurl:XSPUrl = new XSPUrl("");
     langurl.setAddress(context.getUrl().toString());
     langurl.setParameter("mylang","de");
     return langurl}]]>
    </xe:this.href>
</xe:basicLeafNode>
```

Is context.getUrl() not a "real" XSPUrl object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

silly error, but (as an excuse) it was mixed this some other code, not as simple as in my example posted here.

Solution: XSPUrl.setParameter() does not return any value

```
var u:XSPUrl = context.getUrl();
u.setParameter("mylang","de");
return u
```

does it :-)